# Is there a topological space which is simply connected but not local path connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Is there a topological space which is simply connected but not local path connected?
I think these two properties have no relation at all but I can't find a example.

Comment: You might enjoy *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen and Seebach.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology#List_of_mentioned_counterexamples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Cantor-Knaster-Kuratowski Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) is constructed by taking the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ in $[0,1]\times\{0\}\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and drawing a line to $p=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$ from each $c\in \mathcal{C}$. This is homotopy-equivalent to a point, hence is simply connected, but as each point in the Cantor set is a limit point of itself, any open set not containing $p$ will not be path connected.

Comment: Nitpick: Maps are homotopic, spaces are homotopy-equivalent.

Comment: @Neal: Thanks; edited :)

Comment: Why this is homotopy equivalent to a point

Comment: Use a straight-line homotopy along each line segment in the fan to get a deformation retraction from the fan to a point.

Comment: "any open set not containing $p$ will not be path connected" - what is $p$?

Comment: In general, mapping cones of "bad" spaces often have this behavior. If you take the mapping cone of the Hawaiian earring, it's simply connected, locally connected, and still not locally simply connected.

Comment: @immibis: Sorry, $p$ is now defined as the point to which the lines are drawn.

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  The comb space works.  It is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
$$(\{0\} \times [0,1])  \cup   ([0,1] \times \{0\}) \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} (\{1/n\} \times [0,1] )$$
It is easy to see that this space is contractible (collapse the tines of the comb to the $x$-axis, then contract the interval) and hence simply connected, but it is not locally path connected.  There is no open neighborhood of a point $(0, y)$ with $0 < y \leq 1$ that is path connected.

Answer (score 6):

quasi-circle would be another useful counter example, this is not locally path connected. See here ex1.3.7  that it is simple connected (http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/opg/S1.3.pdf) .[image]

Comment: Isn't this called *Warsaw circle*? Some links: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology)#Examples), [ncatlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle) and [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=warsaw+circle+topology&tbm=isch).

Comment: @MartinSleziak not sure about the name, but hatcher named it as quasi-circle